# how can I calculate $a_{n+3}=a_n+a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}$?

Tags: recursion, modular-arithmetic

recently I need to calculate this: $a(n+1)=((a(n-2)+a(n-1)+a(n)) \bmod 10000)$

and get $a(20000000)$ (for example).

I know `RecurrenceTable`,but

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == Mod[a[n] + a[n - 1] + a[n - 2], 10000], 
a[1] == 1, a[2] == 1, a[3] == 1}, a, {n, 1, 20000000}] // Last
```

require a bit of long time.(and extra space)

using `RSolve` is also useless.

`Nest` seems only support $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$

this is also not so useful.

```
a[1] == 1;
a[2] == 1;
a[3] == 1;
a[n_] := a[n] = Mod[a[n - 3] + a[n - 1] + a[n - 2], 100000];
a[20000000]
```

So is there a way which can Space Complexity be $O(1)$ as well as fast? (I know matrix exponentiating by squaring,but it seems hard to write.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Nest[]` is in fact usable here, if you are ingenious enough and willing to wait a little:

```
Last[Nest[Append[Rest[#], Mod[{1, 1, 1}.#, 100000]] &, {1, 1, 1}, 20000000 - 3]]
   16287
```

An alternative is to use an *undocumented* function for modular matrix exponentiation:

```
Mod[First[Algebra`MatrixPowerMod[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}},
                                 20000000 - 3, 100000].{1, 1, 1}], 100000]
   16287
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) for the initial conditions.

```
Clear[a, n]

a[1] = 1;
a[2] = 1;
a[3] = 1;
a[n_] := a[n] = Mod[a[n - 3] + a[n - 1] + a[n - 2], 100000];
Last[a /@ Range[4, 20000000]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {107.222, 16287} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar approach to JM...

```
mat = {{1, 1, 1},
       {1, 0, 0},
       {0, 1, 0}};

init = {1,1,1};

next[vec_] := Mod[mat.vec, 100000];

First@Nest[next, {1, 1, 1}, 20000000-3] // Timing

(*  {42.0625, 16287}  *)
```

Inspired by JM's second approach, but using what is documented...still pretty fast. I thought it might overflow, but no problem.

```
First@Mod[Mod[MatrixPower[mat, 20000000 - 3], 100000].{1, 1, 1}, 100000] // Timing

(* {0.03125, 16287} *)
```

Comment: You can simplify your second approach by using the action form of `MatrixPower[]`: `First[Mod[MatrixPower[mat, 20000000 - 3, {1, 1, 1}], 100000]]`.

Comment: Alternatively there is ``Algebra`MatrixPowerMod``. Unfortunately it does not (so far as I am aware) take that optional vector argument. But at least it limits the intermediate integer swell.

Comment: Yup, I was riffing on JM's answer, which uses it. That one was "too cheap to meter" time-wise. Very nice.